# Как мне вывести таблицу MYsql в PHP?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Я впервые встречаюсь с этой средой, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.php

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, у нас имеется таблица blog с полями name_blog и text_blog, тогда
в простейшем случае работа с базой будет выглядеть так:

```
   // Подключение к базе: где $hostname - сервер, $username - имя юзера БД,
   // $password - пароль юзера, $basename - имя базы с которой мы будем работать
   $hostname = 'localhost';
   $username = 'user1';
   $passwordname = '123';
   $basename = 'bd_blog';
   $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $passwordname, $basename) or die       ('Невозможно открыть базу');
   // Формируем запрос из таблицы с именем blog
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `blog`";
   $result = $conn->query($sql); 
   // В цикле перебираем все записи таблицы и выводим их
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   {
       // Оператором echo выводим на экран поля таблицы name_blog и text_blog
       echo 'Название блога: '.$row['name_blog'];
       echo 'Текст блога: '.$row['text_blog'];
   }
```

Данный пример реализован с помощью mysqli, также можно реализовать с помощью PDO.
Чтобы изучить более сложные приемы приема, передачи и вывода данных, читайте документацию по php и sql. Надеюсь мой пример поможет Вам девушка).

Comment: Спасибо!!Да,более менее разобралсь и поняла,а как вот теперь сделать так, чтобы данные в таблице можно было редактировать и измененный вид сохранялся в той же таблице